# AngularJS: is there a debug mode for typos in bindings?

Tags: angularjs

I've just wasted half an hour hunting for what turned out to be...

```
<select.... data-ng-options="x as x.name for x in customerController_clipped.options"
```

instead of

```
<select.... data-ng-options="x as x.name for x in customerController_Clipped.options"
```

That is, a one-character typo - in this case, a 'clip...' instead 'Clip...'
Sure, it's easy to see it when it's isolated above - but think of this inside huge HTML content, and you now know why I ask:

Is there a way to ask AngularJS to report any failures in names of bindings, to ease our debugging? A simple console logging of this kind of failure would suffice, instead of a silent operation that leaves our components empty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything built in for doing this, though maybe you could raise with angular.js as a feature request, or try writing a pull request for putting an option in `$parseProvider`? If you want to do this the only way I can see right now is by altering the code in the `$parse` service which does the interpreting of any expressions.

I've [plunked](http://plnkr.co/edit/QtDCQs?p=preview) a quick test to see how easy it is. The original code is from angular 1.1.5. Search for ANDYMOD in the angular-1.1.5.js file to see the code I've edited. This basically adds a `console.log` for whenever the `y` and `z` parts of a 'x.y.z' expression are undefined or null, rather than ignoring it.

This is in no way a production-worthy solution, and doesn't work it you want to use `ng-csp`, but it shows something can be done at least. Maybe you can sub these few lines in if you ever need to test again...

Comment: Thanks, Andy - in my HTML partials I always start from a model, so I have access paths like ... ng-model="someModel.someVariable". If I understand correctly, your patch detects these, so I will mark this as asnwered. I still think Angular should offer an official way for doing this, IMHO.

Comment: Yes. It will still ignore when `someModel` is undefined to avoid noise while models are being initialised. But any other parts of dot-separated identifiers in a watch or binding will be logged when they are null or undefined.