# Debugging Angular front-ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are working on a relatively simple Angular front-end (version 1.4x), and we're constantly battling very small bugs caused by typos. For example, we get data from the server and then put it in the scope:

```
...
$scope.result = data.results
...
```

See the plural there? This code just works, putting `undefined` in $scope.result. We would like to get some sort of warning of notification when this happens. Static analysis tools such as JSLint can't help us there, because they have absolutely no way of knowing what the server returns.

This problem manifests itself again in HTML templates:

```
...
<p>The result is: <emph>{{results}}</emph></p>
...
```

Here, too, we get no notification whatsoever we tried accessing an `undefined` property.

Is there a way to get any kind of notification for this? We find ourselves spending a lot of time on these bugs.

Comment: This is the solution I use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321104/angularjs-is-there-a-debug-mode-for-typos-in-bindings

Comment: This may be a bit off topic but another option would be using IDE/Editor which can detect typos more intelligently than notepad, say Sublime Text and Notepad++ even have intellisense within one file, and WebStorm shows notifications whenever names/properties contain typos

Comment: We're using PyCharm, and the problem is not the typos but the usage of undefined properties. I'll rephrase.

Comment: @gtlambert, thanks, this may solve the second problem but not the first, which is straight Javascript code that doesn't get parsed by Angular.

Comment: *"...they have absolutely no way of knowing what the server returns."*. So just define types for properties and responses (jsdoc comments, etc). If you use JetBrains IDE it would be able to detect problems like "resultt" if specify that "result" is expected.

Comment: @dfsq - Define the types of properties - where? It makes sense to document the API on the server side, but the server is in Python.

Comment: You document frontend code, specify what services return, what properties returned data contains, etc. This allows IDE to validate your data statically.

Comment: OMG I hate Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm will handle these sorts of issue for you. For example in my code {{f.$error}} I placed an extra r on the end and WS flags this a both a misspelling and Unresolved variable $errorr. WebStorm does an execlent job of handling many different frame works to include Angular and Node.

Comment: We're using PyCharm which should contain everything WebStorm has. It finds typos but it doesn't handle Javascript code looking for properties that aren't sent from the server. It also doesn't handle Angular templates accessing an undefined property. This may be a Javascript issue.

Comment: You have to make sure you have the JavaScript Debugger, JavaScript Support loaded. While they are basically the same the do not come with all of the same options turned on/loaded. I also checked and I'm not sure if I added or it came with but I have an AngularJS plugin loaded.

Comment: @zmbq https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/using-angularjs.html Maybe you upgraded and angular did not get enabled?